# Печать в bash-скрипте

Tags: makefile

В makefile увидел следующую конструкцию:

```
.PHONY: .build
.build:
    $(info #Building...)
```

В консоли появится:

> #Building...

Чем это отличается от

```
echo "#Building..."
```

Важно заметить, что `echo` работает как в терминале, так и в makefile, а первый кейс работает только в makefile.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, какая связь в вопросе bash и makefile?

Comment: Ну, как... bash умеет исполнять команды внутри makefile. Плюс, меня интересует, почему `$(info ...)` работает внутри makefile и не работает в терминале @0xdb

Comment: Вы не правы, bash никогда не работал с makefile, для этого есть make, который может быть запущен в другой оболочке как и вообще без неё.

Comment: @0xdb но, погодите, я могу выполнить bash-команды внутри makefile. Поясните

Comment: Уточнения к "я могу выполнить bash-команды внутри makefile": выполнит комманду программа make, а внутри makefile только указания для неё, что надо делать.

Comment: Можете, и не обязательно bash, любой shell. make запустит subshell обычно определённый в переменной `$(SHELL)` и там выполнится комманда.   
Извините, я удалил один комментарий, т.к. там было не совсем верное высказыание.

Comment: в данном случае info — это [функция программы make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html#index-info). к программе bash она не имеет абсолютно никакого отношения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

это вызов встроенной в интерпретатор *make* [функции `info`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html#index-info):

```
$(info строка)
```

а это вызов встроенной в интерпретатор, выполняющий функции *оболочки*, команды `echo` (хотя и не во все реализации оболочек эта команда входит: [стандарт posix требует наличия хотя бы отдельной программы с таким именем](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)):

```
echo строка
```

---

одно с другим не связано никаким образом. хотя результат применения практически идентичен.